# Attach Durandal child routes to main rute object

Tags: durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I would like to ask if it's  possible to attache child routes to they're parent route?

If all routes are defined on the main route then I can use the route object to build my 2-level menus.

I also just want to set-up all routes in one file.

Answer (score 0):

All the route configuration will be present in the navigation model which you can access using router.navigationModel. Even though you configure your router inside a parent viewmodel, the child routers will still be present inside the navigation model.